# Различие в отображении шрифта в Sublime Text 3 и Phpstorm 2017.4

Tags: phpstorm, шрифты, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Установил шрифт Monaco (ну понравился он мне).
Размер шрифта 11.

[image: В сублайме выглядит вот так]

[image: В шторме вот так]

Первый скрин сублайм, второй шторм.
И разница наблюдается при любом шрифте.

Comment: И что? Ну разница, и что? IDE-то разные... (Это был лёгкий троллинг, потому что вы не озвучили проблему и что вы хотите получить). Хочется стилизовать - марш в настройки, редактор и вперёд стилизовать под саблайм (изменять размер шрифта). А ещё, что вам мешает покрутить колёсиком с зажатым Ctrl в самом редакторе?...

Comment: Ну я всегда думал что один и тот же шрифт должен отображаться одинаково в разных программах. Разве нет?

Comment: а шрифт и выглядит одинаково. Отличаются только размеры.

Comment: @intro94, шрифты далеко не одинаково выглядят. В sublime высота больше.

Comment: На скриншоте я вижу, что пропорционально они выглядят одинаково, лишь размерами отличаются - у саблайма больший размер установлен. А по факту - не всё ли равно? У шторма вполне мебе адекватный шрифт. Пользуюсь им и горя не знаю. А на саблайм забил сразу же...

Comment: @intro94, размер одинаковый в обоих случаях =11

Comment: @thecoder я говорю не о размерах в пунктах, а о размере самого шрифта. Просто увеличьте размер в пунктах и всё. Или, опять же, Ctrl+колёсико в помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается из-за java у шторма шрифт мельче. Поэтому нужно выставлять размер больше.